# Different md5 sum from same file

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, md5

I'm counting md5 sum from video file from iphone gallery. Each time i choose the same file it has different md5 sum. I also check the data length in bytes and it stay the same. So my question is - why? Here is some code with one from many ways i was trying to make it.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{   
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"])
    {
        NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
        [videoData retain];
        NSLog(@"VIDEO DATA MD5: %@", [videoData md5]);
        NSLog(@"VIDEO DATA LEN: %d", videoData.length);
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

[Implementation of MD5 Method](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/core-services/create-md5-hash-from-nsstring-nsdata-or-file.html):

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

@implementation NSData(MD5)

- (NSString*)MD5
{
  // Create byte array of unsigned chars
  unsigned char md5Buffer[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

  // Create 16 byte MD5 hash value, store in buffer
  CC_MD5(self.bytes, self.length, md5Buffer);

  // Convert unsigned char buffer to NSString of hex values
  NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
  for(int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) 
    [output appendFormat:@"%02x",md5Buffer[i]];

  return output;
}

@end
```

Comment: what's the implementation of `md5`?

Comment: [implementation of md5](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/core-services/create-md5-hash-from-nsstring-nsdata-or-file.html)

Comment: When you get the data twice in a row, does calling `isEqualToData:` return `YES` or `NO`? I'm wondering if there isn't some metadata that's updated by accessing the file (particularly something like 'last accessed') so that every time you get it you have the same video but different metadata?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are doing the comparison? Are you possibly using == to compare two strings, instead of `[string1 isEqualToString:string2]`?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this behavior. It happens regardless of the hash function chosen (I tried MD5, SHA1, and SHA256).

The issue appears to be `NSData`. I create two `NSData` instances from the **exact same file** and then use `[data1 isEqualTo:data2]` and that returns true. However, running those through the `CC_SHA1` hash algorithm returns a different hash for each.

To work around this, drop `NSData`. Instead, open the file using lower-level C APIs. Here's an example in C. Note the "create" convention—YOU are responsible for releasing the returned `char*` buffer when you're done. Using this approach will produce an identical hash each time.

```
char* _Nullable createBufferWithContentsOfFileAndReportLength(NSString* _Nonnull fileToScan, long* _Nullable length)
{
    char const *pathToFile = [fileToScan cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    FILE *file = fopen(pathToFile, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to open file: %@", fileToScan);
        return NULL;
    }
    
    //
    //  Get the file length.
    //  'fileLength' will be the number of bytes in the file. It will not include a null terminator or EOF. Some UTF8 characters require more than one byte, so we
    //  can't guarantee that fileLength is also the number of characters.
    //  NOTE: We don't use the fseek()/ftell()/rewind approach because it's not secure. See CERT FIO19-C advisory for details.
    //
    int fd = fileno(file);
    if (fd < 0) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to get a file descriptor for: %@", fileToScan);
        fclose(file);
        return NULL;
    }
    struct stat statBuffer;
    if (fstat(fd, &statBuffer) == -1) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to retrieve stats about this file: %@", fileToScan);
        fclose(file);
        return NULL;
    }
    long fileLength = statBuffer.st_size;
    
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * (fileLength + 1));     // enough memory to read the entire file, plus a spot for the null terminator
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to allocate memory for: %@", fileToScan);
        fclose(file);
        return NULL;
    }
    
    fread(buffer, fileLength, sizeof(char), file);
    buffer[fileLength] = '\0';                              // No +1; this is zero-indexed. If fileLength is 5 characters, the 5th slot in the array needs to be the null terminator.
    fclose(file);

    if (length != NULL) {
        *length = fileLength + 1;
    }
    
    return buffer;
}
```